# How long for a invitation on careers 2.0 to come through?

Tags: support, jobs, invitation

Hi, a friend of mine invited me to the careers 2.0

Except, I never got an email for it ? Is that normal ?

Does it go through some process ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you should receive the email immediately.  Your friend should be able to go into Careers and see the status of the invitation.  Perhaps they used the wrong email address?  If so, they could let us know here and we can refund the invite.